# Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/x-data-grid' in 'C:\Users\Syndicate\Documents\GitHub\simserp\sims\src\components\modules\country'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csHn6.jpg)

I was working on the  `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"` version, and now the version is changed. I am looking the way for :

```js
import { GridOverlay, DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
```

But it is not working.
can anyone help me in setting up both the version and documentation for the older version so that I go with both version in my application.

Comment: Can you just put a whole error output

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 23):

#### TL;DR

Step 1.

```bash
// with npm
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

// with yarn
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Step 2.

```bash
// with npm
npm install @mui/x-data-grid

// with yarn
yarn add @mui/x-data-grid
```

Step 3.

```js
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'
```

---

#### Long Text

Our company also encountered the same problem when migrating, and finally solved it perfectly.

The reason for the above error is because `@mui/x-data-grid` is dependent on Material UI v5, so you have to install it, or you [can be used with Material UI v4 with some additional steps](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/migration-v4/#using-mui-core-v4-with-v5).

> This is a reference guide for upgrading your site from MUI X v4 to v5. MUI X v5 is fully compatible with Material UI v5 and MUI System v5 and can be used with Material UI v4 and MUI System v4 with some additional steps. Most breaking changes are renaming of CSS classes or variables to improve the consistency of the data grid.

- Refer to [MUI X doc](https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v4/#introduction)

**You may be wondering, but what should I do if I use Material UI v4 now?**
According to our experience and the [information provided by the official Material](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/migration-v4/#migrating-mui-core-from-v4), it is no problem to have the v4 package and the v5 package at the same time, so you can install the Material UI v5 first and let `@mui/x-data-grid` can be used, waiting for the spare time to migrate the v4 components to the v5 usage.

> We strongly recommend you migrate Material UI to v5 when using MUI X v5. However, this might not be possible, depending on the complexity of the application. The alternative is to install Material UI v5 and configure it to keep Material UI v4 running alongside.

- Refer to [MUI X doc](https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-data-grid-v4/#migrating-mui-core-from-v4)

Comment: @Olivier Tassinari thanks for the update

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I wanted to clarify. Material UI: design system components, Material Design only today. MUI X: advanced components: MUI: an organization.

Answer (score 8):

Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/x-data-grid'

Means you don't have this module installed

If you find this error for any other modules meaning is the same you have to install that specific module

```
npm install @mui/x-data-grid
```

Answer (score 3):

npm i @mui/x-data-grid install this one first

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have installed the dependency `@mui/x-data-grid` VS Code may nag you with this error, the solution is to restart the VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer**

*Step-1*
install dependency

```
npm install @mui/material


npm install @mui/x-data-grid
```

*Step-2*
Restart VS Code

**Note-**
If you find it useful then please upvote this

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34417639)